# QGIS 3x label appearance at different zoom level

Tags: qgis

I have a problem.
In my QGIS project,[image] all the labels appear the same despite the zoom level. What looks good when the zoom is big, it's not as great when zooming out.

I found a way to get it disappeared,
[Label display at different zoom level of single shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214208/label-display-at-different-zoom-level-of-single-shapefile)

but I need it smaller only. Is there any way to set the different font sizes for different zoom levels?

I've already the expression based on one of the table value:

```
  CASE
  WHEN "Visible" = 1 then color_rgb (0, 0, 0)
  End
```

How can I integrate this expression with the answer below?

Comment: Have you checked https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305845/label-font-size-and-scale-qgis-3-0 ?

Comment: Also check this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/230138/63384

Comment: These 2 threads don't help me really. The first one is fine, but I need a rough range i.e. when scale smaller than 1:1000 then font size is 10, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set an expression based rule for the font size, something along the lines of :

```
if(@map_scale<1000, 10, 30 /log(8, @map_scale))
```

This expression will make so the font size is 9 at a scale of 1:1001 to 5.8 at 1:50000 for example

you can play with the `30/log(8, @map_scale)` expression to try to have something that suits you better.

[image]

Comment: How should I integrate it with: 
CASE
  WHEN "Visible" = 1 then color_rgb (0, 0, 0)
  End
?
I have already got this expression, which is needed.

Comment: @MKR the expression for size and color are put in different place, there are data defined override for almost all label setting, you just put each each expression in it's own place

Comment: I cannot really do that, because I set these expressions for all my font groups. If I do so, then they shift between one rule and another as I zoom in and out.

Comment: i've edited my answer to show you were you need to set the expression and as @J.R said each attribute of the label can be based on its own expression or field or anything else

Comment: @MKR what to you mean by "font groups" ?

Comment: I set 4 separate rules for my fonts (labels). I misspelled it. Sorry. Anyway, now since I have the screenshot it's good. It started to work at least. I need to play with it for about a while.